# Button posts back

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net-3.5

I have added a "Copy to Clipboard" button on a web page. When user selects a row from a grid, some of the details are stored in a hidden textarea control.
Also, a hidden div on the page (record details) is made visible; it contains the "Copy to Clipboard" button.

When "Copy to clipboard" button is clicked, the content of the hidden textarea is copied to clipboard. This is just an HTML button with its onclick set in javascript function. Also, the content of textarea as well as the detail div content are populated client side, so I can't see why postback happens.

I noticed that when the page is initially loaded it works fine: I select a record from grid, the "detail" section of the page is populated (client side) which includes the clipboard button. Now, if I do a search which requires a postback to filter the grid, then select a record (updates content of details div) and click on the clipboard button, it posts back.
Here is the relevant parts of the code:

```
<textarea id="taDSSInfo" style="display:none"></textarea> 
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnlDetail" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>     
        <controls for displaying record detail >
        <input type="image" id="ibCTC" src="Clipboard.png" />
        ....
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

// Set textarea's content, based on data from grid's selected record
taDSSInfo = document.getElementById('taDSSInfo');
var text = '';
text += 'Laptop IP: ' + record["IPADDR"] + '\r\n';                    
....                    
text += 'Finance Number: ' + record["FINANCENUMBER"] + '\r\n';                    
taDSSInfo.innerText = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, '\n');
```

This is the binding event of button to handle copy to clipboard. It is at the bottom of the .aspx file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function bindEvent(el, eventName, eventHandler) {
        if (el.addEventListener){
            el.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, false); 
        } 
        else if (el.attachEvent){
            el.attachEvent('on'+eventName, eventHandler);
        }
    }

    var ibCTC = document.getElementById('ibCTC');

    bindEvent(ibCTC, 'click',function(event) {
        if (document.all)
        {
            if (window.clipboardData && clipboardData.setData)
            {
                var taDSSInfo = document.getElementById('taDSSInfo');
                var textToCopy = taDSSInfo.innerText;
                window.clipboardData.clearData('Text');
                window.clipboardData.setData('Text', textToCopy);
                //alert (window.clipboardData.getData ('Text'));
            }
        }
        else
            alert ("Copy to clipboard is supported in IE only");
        return false;
    });            

</script>
```

Comment: I think on a an event that causes postback, like searching that updates the grid, the script that binds the button's click event does not get executed so it just does what a button does (postback) without copying anything to clipboard. How to solve it?

Comment: I moved the button outside update panel and problem went away.